# How to use Android EditText Data to populate online XML

Tags: php, android, xml, listview

I currently have an app that shows a listview of data that it gets from the internet.

Similar to the tutorial [Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)
I am using a HTML file, and a webview right now, in order to add new data to the online XML. Like this:

```
<div id="stylized" class="myform">

<form action="http:site.com/test/update.php" method="GET">

    <label>Name
        <span class="small">Name of Event</span>
    </label>
<input type="text" name="title">
```

Now, anytime I fill in the above field "title" gets updated online by my .php script. That works flawlessly, with multiple fields.

I just want to know how I can get rid of the tacky webview. I created a custom form using editText, layouts, and buttons. But how can I use the new form to update the online XML. What is the best way to grab the data out of the editText and pass it to the  `<form action="http:site.com/test/update.php" method="GET">` file?

Thanks

Comment: I dont understand what do you want to achieve? do you want to send data from your android to your update script to update the mysql and therefore update the XML?

Comment: Yes the update.php is fine. I just need to get the data out of my EditText and send it to the update script.

Comment: well you need to use AsyncTask to use POST or GET to the URL within the AsyncTask you have to do `URLConnection` to your script, you can add GET parameter according to your script and then execute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Android's built-in Http client to send a GET request to your server.

1. Retrieve data from EditText and process it with [URLEncoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html) it to prepare GET request:

   ```
   String getUrl = "http://example.com/test/update.php?data=" + URLEncoder.encode(editText.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
   ```
2. Make an Http GET request using [HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) Android Http client:

   ```
   URL url = new URL(getUrl);
   HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   ```
3. Read server response.

   ```
   InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
   StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
   int len = -1;
   while ((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1)
       s.append(new String(buffer, "UTF-8"));
   is.close();
   ```
4. Close connection:

   ```
   urlConnection.disconnect();
   ```

Comment: Awesome! But now how can I have the above code find the EditText data and send it when I hit the submit button?